# How to get the count of account numbers my query is returning, using count(case when)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s.branch AS [Branch]
    , s.CREATEDBYUSER AS [Teller Number]
    , acct.accountnumber AS [Account Number]
    , COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.CLOSEDATE is null 
        AND s.CHARGEOFFDATE is NULL
        then s.PARENTACCOUNT
        else 0
        END
    ) AS [Shares]
    , CASE WHEN s.CLOSEDATE is null 
        AND s.CHARGEOFFDATE is NULL 
        THEN s.balance 
        else 0
    END AS [SharesBalance]
    , CASE WHEN s.CLOSEDATE is null 
        AND s.CHARGEOFFDATE is NULL
        THEN s.TYPE
        ELSE 0
    END AS [Share Type]
    , CASE WHEN s.CLOSEDATE is null 
        AND s.CHARGEOFFDATE is NULL
        then s.DESCRIPTION 
        ELSE NULL
    END AS [Share Description]
from ARCUSYM000.dbo.ACCOUNT acct
    left join ARCUSYM000.dbo.savings s
        on acct.ACCOUNTNUMBER = s.PARENTACCOUNT and s.ProcessDate = acct.ProcessDate
where acct.CLOSEDATE is null  
    AND s.CLOSEDATE is null 
    AND s.chargeoffdate is null 
    AND ((s.OPENDATE >= @StartDate AND s.OPENDATE <= @EndDate)
    OR (acct.OPENDATE >= @StartDate AND acct.OPENDATE <= @EndDate))
    AND acct.memberstatus = 0 
    AND s.branch is not null 
    AND s.branch IN (@BranchNum)
    AND s.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
    AND acct.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
GROUP BY s.BRANCH
    , s.CREATEDBYUSER
    , acct.ACCOUNTNUMBER
    , s.CLOSEDATE
    , s.CHARGEOFFDATE
    , s.BALANCE
    , s.TYPE
    , s.DESCRIPTION
    , s.SHARECODE
    , s.OVERDRAFTTOLERANCE
    , s.OPENDATE
ORDER BY s.CREATEDBYUSER, acct.ACCOUNTNUMBER
```

Right now I am getting the count of account numbers per each share type. If there is more than one entry for an account number, I'd like to count how many entries there are.

I have tried using partition, and that wasn't working either.

[image: Current Result:]

[image: Desired Result]

Answer (score 0):

If you can add up the `count(distinct)`s to get what you want (as in your example, you can use window functions:

```
SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.CLOSEDATE is null AND s.CHARGEOFFDATE is NULL
                        THEN s.PARENTACCOUNT
                   END
          )
    ) OVER (PARTITION BY acct.accountnumber) AS [Shares]
```

This is a bit more complicated if you need a `COUNT(DISTINCT)` over all the rows for an account.

Note:  `ELSE 0` with `COUNT(DISTINCT)` seems suspicious.  I removed the `ELSE` clause.  The default is `NULL` and will not be counted.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT q.Branch
, q.[Teller Number]
, q.[Account Number]
, COUNT(q.Shares) OVER (PARTITION BY q.[Account Number]) AS [Shares]
, q.SharesBalance
, q.[Share Type]
, q.[Share Description]
FROM(

    SELECT DISTINCT
    s.branch AS [Branch]
    , s.CREATEDBYUSER AS [Teller Number]
    , acct.accountnumber AS [Account Number]
    , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.CLOSEDATE is null 
        AND s.CHARGEOFFDATE is NULL
        AND (s.OPENDATE >= @StartDate AND s.OPENDATE <= @EndDate)
        then s.PARENTACCOUNT
        END) AS [Shares]
    , CASE WHEN s.CLOSEDATE is null 
    AND s.CHARGEOFFDATE is NULL 
    THEN s.balance 
    else 0
    END AS [SharesBalance]
    , CASE WHEN s.CLOSEDATE is null 
    AND s.CHARGEOFFDATE is NULL
    THEN s.TYPE
    ELSE 0
    END AS [Share Type]
    , CASE WHEN s.CLOSEDATE is null 
    AND s.CHARGEOFFDATE is NULL
    then s.DESCRIPTION 
    ELSE NULL
    END AS [Share Description]
    from ARCUSYM000.dbo.ACCOUNT acct
    left join ARCUSYM000.dbo.savings s
        on acct.ACCOUNTNUMBER = s.PARENTACCOUNT and s.ProcessDate = acct.ProcessDate
    where acct.CLOSEDATE is null  
        AND s.CLOSEDATE is null 
        AND s.chargeoffdate is null 
        AND ((s.OPENDATE >= @StartDate AND s.OPENDATE <= @EndDate)
            OR (acct.OPENDATE >= @StartDate AND acct.OPENDATE <= @EndDate))
        AND acct.memberstatus = 0 
        AND s.branch is not null 
        AND s.branch IN (@BranchNum)
        AND s.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
        AND acct.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
    GROUP BY s.BRANCH
        , s.CREATEDBYUSER
        , acct.ACCOUNTNUMBER
        , s.CLOSEDATE
        , s.CHARGEOFFDATE
        , s.BALANCE
        , s.TYPE
        , s.DESCRIPTION
        , acct.STATEMENTMAILCODE
        , s.SHARECODE
        , s.OVERDRAFTTOLERANCE
        , s.OPENDATE
        , s.PARENTACCOUNT
) q
GROUP BY q.Branch
, q.[Teller Number]
, q.[Account Number]
, q.SharesBalance
, q.Shares
, q.[Share Type]
, q.[Share Description]
```

I ended up making a subquery out of my query and got the result I wanted.